# Replace Captured group with constant value

Tags: regex

I have an string like this

```
sheet2.xml/xl/abc/workbook.xls/prest.ppt/download/images/sabbath.jpeg
```

I want the output to be like this

```
sheet.xml,xl/abc/workbook.xls,prest.ppt,download/images/sabbath.jpeg
```

I got a regex to match the only the '/' after .file extensions but not able to replace them with a constant ","

```
\b\.\w+(?=/)\b(/)
```

This regex matches the "/" after each file extensions but how do i replace it with ","

Any suggestions ?

Comment: What tool/programming language are you using to execute your regex ?

Comment: Which flavour of regex?

Comment: Its a java based regex.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a Java-compatible regex. Please have a look if you haven't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your programming language or the tool you are using, the following example could need tweaks in order to work properly.

You have to match the extension inside a `group` to be able to replace it properly later on

Here is [an example on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/T5jWJn/1)

Answer (score 2):

If your regex flavour supports resetting matches, you can use that here! This is a PCRE regex:

```
\b\.\w+(?=\/)\b\K(\/)
               ^^
     Here we reset the match
```

So only the last `/` will be in the match, then you can just replace it with `,`.

If `\K` is not supported,  Try this:

```
(\b\.\w+(?=\/)\b)\/
```

and replace with

```
$1,
```

The trick here is to move the file extension part to group 1. Then in the replacement you could say "group 1 and a comma".

A slightly faster version, suggested by ctwheels in the comments:

```
(\b\.\w+)\/\b
```

Comment: Nice approach, slightly faster and shorter: `\b\.\w+\K\/\b` and `(\b\.\w+)\/\b`

Comment: @ctwheels Thank you for your suggestion.